# Ltspice ac anlysis with dc offset

Tags: ltspice, low-pass

I am doing ac analysis of a simple passive RC low pass filter. The input is a 2 V peak to peak sinusoidal signal. R=1.2k and c=12nF. I want to add a 2.5 V dc offset to the input signal. When I change the dc offset value of the signal generator I always see the same magnitude value. With a 2.5 V offset it must be 13.1 dB at low frequencies but I always see 6 dB. So, how can I see the effect of the offset voltage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AC analysis uses a linearized representation of the circuit around the bias point. DC analysis calculates the bias point.

Given that R and C are linear components, the element equations are the same. However, your offset is simply a bias point, which will be removed from the circuit during linearization, thus having no influence in an AC analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Actually I recognized this when I do a transient simulation with an offset voltage. The absolute magnitude of the signal does not change with offset voltage.